# PHP: Curl POST request to external Oath2 API

Tags: php, api, curl

I'll try to sketch our situation:

- We have a Wordpress website that needs to connect to an Oath2 API
- I have little experience yet using API's and PHP
- We are using a PHP-Oath2 library, which can be found here:
  https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2/tree/master/src/OAuth2

The method from the libary where we're stuck is executeRequest.
This method can be found on line 404 (oh the irony) of https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2/blob/master/src/OAuth2/Client.php

Now, like I said, I've little experience in PHP so my way of debugging is just echo'ing the status of variables at given points in the script.
Amateuristic as this may be, I could at least verify that the url and parameters are correct. I could print the complete URL (dummy parameter values ofc):

> Mind the following parameters used: `code`, `redirect_uri`,
>   `grant_typen` `client_id` and `client_Secret`.
>
> https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token?code=irsyB0VSmg4V5dVjHFgdl85iRvvu3gYpsuIE4cOk&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycallbackurl.com%2Fmy-page%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=5d6t5ev5a6d8&client_secret=pada9c54a6sc

When you execute this request, you'll get a JSON error message. Which is normal, as I cannot give you our client_id and client_secret:

```
{"error":"error_occured","error_description":"Client authentication failed."}
```

When I execute this manually in my browser (with the correct parameter values), I get the desired JSON result:

> {"access_token":"fa4a6s4axsaxxsfacc56c4aca8acac4q6d5z4fsv","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"X5s1aq56xaq6bhz56aGY6SCb9845465czxqde56a"}

The problem is, when CURL builds and executes this as a POST request, I get an error JSON result:

```
{"error":"error_occured","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \u0022code\u0022 parameter."}
```

I can verify the status of the following CURL options (mind you that the code bypasses ssl verification, line 462 in the Client.php file):

- CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = true
- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false
- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = false
- CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  = 'POST'
- CURLOPT_POST = true
- CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS = url encoded parameter string

example:
code=irsyB0VSmg4V5dVjHFgdl85iRvvu3gYpsuIE4cOk&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycallbackurl.com%2Fmy-page%2Fgrant_type=authorization_code&client_id=5d6t5ev5a6d8&client_secret=pada9c54a6sc

- CURLOPT_URL = https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token
- CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => empty array

When executing this Curl handler like this:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

He does successfully reach out to the API and returns the result, but the JSON result shows a parameter error, claiming that the code is incorrect.
But I know that it is correct, because when I execute the request manually via the browser, it works. If you go straight to https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token without parameters, you get that very same error.

This just makes me wonder whether curl passes any parameter at all.

Could you please tell me whether you spot an error somewhere in the provided ifno, perhaps in the curl options?
Or could you guide me to a proper way to debug this curl execution (keeping in mind that I'm on Wordpress, if that matters at all).

Please let me know if this post lacks required information.
Thank you in advance.

--EDIT:

The library code is triggered by the following lines of code (again, dummy client id and secret). This method can be found on line 211 of https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2/blob/master/src/OAuth2/Client.php

```
$client = new Client('5d6t5ev5a6d8', 'pada9c54a6sc');
$callBackUrl = 'https://mycallbackurl.com/my-page';
$myResponse = $client->getAccessToken('https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token', 'authorization_code', ['code'=> $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => $callBackUrl]);
```

I've removed the code that puts the header option to an empty array, just to be sure. But when debugging with CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, the result remains the same. It indeed defaults to Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Here's the complete curl_getinfo() array:

> Array ( [url] => https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token
>   [content_type] => application/json [http_code] => 200 [header_size] =>
>   7414 [request_size] => 363 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.073514 [namelookup_time] =>
>   3.9E-5 [connect_time] => 0.006093 [pretransfer_time] => 0.028232 [size_upload] => 216 [size_download] => 231 [speed_download] => 3142
>   [speed_upload] => 2938 [download_content_length] => -1
>   [upload_content_length] => 216 [starttransfer_time] => 0.073476
>   [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>   [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => xxxxx [local_ip] =>
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [local_port] => xxxxx [request_header] => POST
>   /OAuth/index/token HTTP/1.1 Host: oauth.smartschool.be Accept: */*
>   Content-Length: 216 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded )

The result, however, remains the same (still indication that no parameters were passed at all):

> Array ( [result] => Array ( [error] => error_occured
>   [error_description] => The request is missing a required parameter,
>   includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than
>   once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "code" parameter. ) [code]
>   => 200 [content_type] => application/json )

Is there any way to print the parameters / post fields / body from this curl request, to verify that all information was sent?

-- EDIT2:

After using the httbin.org/post link which Tobias provided, I got the following result:

```
Array ( 
    [args] => Array 
        (
        ) 

    [data] => 
    [files] => Array 
        ( 
        ) 

    [form] => Array 
        ( 
            [client_id] => 5d6t5ev5a6d8
            [client_secret] => pada9c54a6sc
            [code] => fa4a6s4axsaxxsfacc56c4aca8acac4q6d5z4fsv
            [grant_type] => authorization_code 
            [redirect_uri] => https://mycallbackurl.com/my-page
        ) 

    [headers] => Array 
        ( 
            [Accept] => */* 
            [Connection] => close 
            [Content-Length] => 216 
            [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
            [Host] => httpbin.org 
        ) 

    [json] => 
    [origin] => 83.xxx.xx.xx
    [url] => https://httpbin.org/post 
)
```

Comparing this to Tobias'example, I don't see any noteworthy differences. I assume this means that our POST request does at least contain all required data. We're still in the dark here then for what possible reason(s) the API does not accept the parameters. Should you come up with some other possible solutions, please don't hesitate to append them. Thanks for this dump link tho, this is really useful!

Comment: Can you add the lines where you call "executeRequest()" and the parameters passed to it?

Comment: I've added the lines that trigger getAccessToken(). This method calls executeRequest() in the end.

Comment: I've tried to set up a MCVE using the provided information + the edit how you call it: https://pastebin.com/HGpW3dLx - However when I call that I immediately get the "Client authentication failed." response that is desired. I'm using PHP 7.2.2. Do you get the error when you call that script in your environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between your testing in browser and the actual code: In the browser, you pass the variables as *GET* parameters, while in your code you are sending a *POST* body.

To debug such issues I often find it easier to use CLI `curl` before going to PHP. When I send the request like this (mind the `Content-Type` header) I managed to get a positive result:

```
curl -X POST --data "code=irsyB0VSmg4V5dVjHFgdl85iRvvu3gYpsuIE4cOk&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycallbackurl.com%2Fmy-page%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=5d6t5ev5a6d8&client_secret=pada9c54a6sc" "https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
{"error":"error_occured","error_description":"Client authentication failed."}
```

I was able to reproduce your error when I forcefully send the request without this header. This is actually not that easy, because using `--data` automatically adds it:

```
curl -X POST --data "code=irsyB0VSmg4V5dVjHFgdl85iRvvu3gYpsuIE4cOk&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycallbackurl.com%2Fmy-page%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=5d6t5ev5a6d8&client_secret=pada9c54a6sc" "https://oauth.smartschool.be/OAuth/index/token" -H "Content-Type: "
{"error":"error_occured","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \u0022grant_type\u0022 parameter."}
```

You need to make sure your code sends the request with the header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I'd guess that PHP-`curl` would also implicitely add it when using `POST(FIELDS)` (analog like the CLI version does), and your issue may be that you "forcefully" set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to an empty array and thus remove it.

To debug the headers that are being sent you can use:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
// curl_exec
$information = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($information);
```

Edit:

What is actually even better to debug is to change your OAuth-URL where the *POST* goes to *https://httpbin.org/post*. This will just mirror everything that was sent to it, so then dump the response you get, it should look like:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

            [data] =>
            [files] => Array
                (
                )

            [form] => Array
                (
                    [client_id] => 5d6t5ev5a6d8
                    [client_secret] => pada9c54a6sc
                    [code] => irsyB0VSmg4V5dVjHFgdl85iRvvu3gYpsuIE4cOk
                    [grant_type] => authorization_code
                    [redirect_uri] => https://mycallbackurl.com/my-page
                )

            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [Accept] => */*
                    [Connection] => close
                    [Content-Length] => 180
                    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                    [Host] => httpbin.org
                )

            [json] =>
            [origin] => 217.***.***.***
            [url] => https://httpbin.org/post
        )

    [code] => 200
    [content_type] => application/json
)
```

And you can hopefully identify what is being sent (and not) from there, including the body data. Not even `curl`s verbose mode shows that unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the effort to reproduce the problem and to explain. I've added some more information to my post, showing the results of my curl_getinfo. Could you perhaps have another look at the outcome and tell me if you can indicate any other problem(s) with it? Thanks you.

Comment: I added another way to debug everything from your request using https://httpbin.org/. Also, I added an MCVE as a comment to your question that however worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips Tobias. I didn't have the time yet to test further, will do that tomorrow. I've awarded you the bounty for your help so far, as it would've expired otherwise. Thank you so far!